# Is there a way to set image quality for webp images in python?

Tags: python, image, webp

Is there a way to set image quality for .webp images in python? For instance, saving a webp image with 70% quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the Pillow module (but it doesn't come with Python by default, use `pip install pillow`)

```py
from PIL import Image               # import the PIL.Image module
img = Image.open("image.webp")      # open your image
img.save("image2.webp", quality=70) # save the image with the given quality
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/webp/   This package seems to be suitable